# Increment Of Pointer Of An Array

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 100, i;
    double D[x];

    for(i=0; i < 100; i++)
        scanf("%f", D++);

    return 0;
}
```

The code has two errors:

1. `"%f"` rather then `"%lf"` - compilation error
2. `D++` - compilation error

But why is `D++` an error? as `D` is a pointer to the first element of the array and `++` can be used on an array, like pointers?

Comment: You can't increment `D` because it is ***not*** a pointer. An array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element, but it's not a pointer in itself. What you probably want is something like `&D[i]` instead.

Comment: Also, when using `scanf` the format `%f` is for `float`.

Comment: Also think a little bit... If `D` really was a pointer, and you could do `D++`, then you would lose the original value of `D`. Once the loop was over, how would you access the data you just read, if you no longer have a pointer to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`D` is not a pointer to the first element of an array.  `D` *is* an array, and an array "decays" into a pointer to its first element in most contexts.

The `++` operator cannot be used on an array because it modifies its operand, and an array is not modifiable (although its element are).

Comment: But we can use the arithmetics of array elements like points, for example *(D++)?

Comment: `*(D++)` is invalid for the same reason `D++` is invalid, i.e. you're trying to increment an array.  You're probably thinking of `(*D)++` which increments the first element of the array.

Comment: When can we use an array with point arithmetics? We can use D+2 to get to the second element of the array, and &(D+2) to access the location of the second element of the array?

Comment: @gbox That's correct, you can do that because those expressions don't attempt to modify the array.  `++` and `--` aren't valid on arrays because they modify their operand.

Comment: Then why &(D+2) can not be used in scanf?

Comment: `&(D+2)` is not a valid expression.  `&` can only be applied to an lvalue, i.e. an addressable object, and `D + 2` does not represent that but is just a pointer value.

Answer (score 0):

you should know that D isn't pointer to first element of array but is a name of array and name of array has a special feature as it has the address of the first element in array but can't be incremented or decremented as it isn't real pointer but it is only the address of the first element in array 
SO keep in your mind ( douple D[x]; "name of array"= D=&D[0])
SO if you want to increment to scan  array elements by user there is two method 
firstly by using array

```
 for(i=0; i < 100; i++)
        scanf("%lu", D[i]);
```

secondly by using pointer

```
douple *ptr=&D[0];
for(i=0; i < 100; i++)
        scanf("%lu", *(ptr+i);
```

As you want to fill array elements by values

```
 *(D+i)=*(ptr+i)=D[i]
```

at the same i